# Counting the number of distinct integers in a permutation

Tags: combinatorics

I can choose from $m$ natural numbers, I have $k$ ordered slots, and I want to place objects in the slots and allow repetitions. How can I count the number of outcomes in which there are $N$ distinct numbers in my list?

For fixed $m$ and $k$ I can calculate these by hand but I haven't generalized it. If $m=4$ and $k=3$ then there are **4** ways to obtain $N=1$ (111, 222, 333, 444), there are **36** ways to get $N=2$, and there are **24** ways to get $N=3$.

How can I find the number of ways to get $N$ distinct integers if $1\le N \le k$? I believe it should be the number of ways to choose $n_1,\ldots ,n_m$ such that $N=\frac{m(m-1)\cdots(m-l+1)}{n_1!\cdots n_m!}$, but I cannot compute that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first choose the distinct numbers that you want, and then put them into the slots. The number of ways to do the former is $\binom{m}{N}$. To put numbers into the slots, you basically want to give each distinct number at least one slot, and then fill up the remaining slots. The number of ways to do this is
$$
\left(\binom{k}{N} \cdot N!\right) \cdot N^{k - N}
$$

Rewriting, we have the total number of ways to choose from $m$ natural numbers, put them into $k$ ordered slots (with repetitions) such that there are $N$ distinct numbers is
$$
\binom{m}{N} \cdot k(k-1)(k-2)\dotsm(k-N+1) \cdot N^{k - N}
$$

(This gives 72 ways for $m = 4$, $k = 3$, $N = 2$ instead of the 36 you mentioned. There might be a counting mistake, perhaps?)

Answer (score 1):

I need to select $N$ numbers from the $m$ naturals, which can be done $\binom{m}{N}$ ways. Given that I have $k$ ordered slots in a given sequence, I now place my $k$ objects from a set of $N$ $N^k$ ways. I then account for all my repeats in that sequence of $k$ objects. This computation may be best solved for using the multinomial coefficient (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).